# If $\sin x = a$, for $x$ in the Second Quadrant, then $\tan x = \text{???}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin x = a$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} < x < \pi$, then which of the following must equal $\tan x$?
>
> a) $\phantom{-}\dfrac 1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$
>
> b) $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$
>
> c) $\phantom{-}\dfrac a{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$
>
> d) $-\dfrac a{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$

I came upon this problem in a recent test.  I wonder if using the quotient identity would be of any help to solve it: $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$? Or maybe a half-angle identity or a double-angle identity maybe used to set up the solution.  Does someone know the correct answer for this problem?  Thank you.

Comment: So, if $\sin(x)=a$, notice that all answers have $1-a^2$ appearing in them.  Yes, the $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ will be useful here.  What is $1-a^2$ in terms of $\sin$?  In terms of $\cos$?  Next, remember what $\tan(x)$ is equal to in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: imagine a right angled triangle with hypotenuse 1 and side opposite angle $x$ of length $a$. then the adjacent side will have length $\sqrt{1-a^2}$

Answer (score 3):

Well you have that $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, and from the Pythagorean identity, we have that
$$\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$$
$$\cos x = \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$
We use the minus version because between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, cosine is negative, and square roots are always positive, so we need to negate it. Ultimately, we get
$$\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$

Comment: It should be mentioned why $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$ should imply that $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ in this specific situation.  Be careful because that is not always true.  (*And is infact not true in this specific situation, look at the domain of $x$ more carefully*)

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for that, I will fix it.

Comment: +1. But: *"... square roots are always positive ..."* Tell that to $\sqrt{0}$. ;)

Comment: @Blue "Principal square roots of non-negative real numbers are always non-negative" is accurate, but doesn't roll off the keyboard so glibly. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (d) $-\frac a{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$

$$\tan x  = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{a}{-\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$

The negative sign is chosen for cosine because $x$ is in the second quadrant.

Alternatively, simply  get the correct magnitude (unsigned value) as $\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$ and then deduce that in the second quadrant, $\tan x$ and $\sin x$ have opposite signs. Either approach gives you the correct answer.